# How to trade risk-adjusted returns?

Tags: volatility, quant-trading-strategies, normal-distribution

Why does dividing daily returns by daily range eliminates fat tails and results in an (almost) gaussian distribution?
And how could that distribution be exploited to enter trades?

Comment: This [question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/1157/35) might be of interest.